# How can I accumulate cells of different lengths into a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

So, I have a cell-array of 1xN vectors of different lengths. I want to append them into a matrix so I can display them with `imagesc`. Obviously the matrix must be the width of the largest vector.  My current code for this is below:

```
tcell = {[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1], []};
lens = cellfun('length', tcell);
rmat = NaN(length(tcell), max(lens));
for i = 1:length(tcell)
    rmat(i, 1:lens(i)) = tcell{i};
end
```

Does anyone know a vectorized solution for this type of problem? I'm not really worried about the speed of this loop because of MATLAB's JIT. I'm just trying to expand my knowledge and this is a case that I come across quite often in my programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one solution that uses [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to first pad each cell with [`NaN`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) values, then [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) to put the cell contents into a matrix:

```
tcell = {[1 2 3], [1 2 3 4 5], [1 2 3 4 5 6], [1], []};  % Sample cell array

maxSize = max(cellfun(@numel, tcell));               % Get the maximum vector size
fcn = @(x) [x nan(1, maxSize-numel(x))];             % Create an anonymous function
rmat = cellfun(fcn, tcell, 'UniformOutput', false);  % Pad each cell with NaNs
rmat = vertcat(rmat{:});                             % Vertically concatenate cells
```

And the output:

```
rmat =

     1     2     3   NaN   NaN   NaN
     1     2     3     4     5   NaN
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```