# How do I combine uneven matrices into a single matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
dt1 dt2 dt3 dt
1   3   6   10
2   4   1   5 
3   6   5   3
4   7   4   1
5   1   2   4
6   2   8
7   8
8
9
10
```

I have the above data which I want to combine in one single matrix (10 x 4). The maximum number of rows is 10. I created a `zeros` matrix.  However, I have a problem since the data doesn't have the same dimensions. How it is possible to get the output as below? Should I sort the data and replace the missing values with 0?

```
1   1   1   1  
2   2   2   0  
3   3   0   3   
4   4   4   4   
5   0   5   5  
6   6   6   0   
7   7   0   0
8   8   8   0
9   0   0   0
10  0   0   10
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accumulating cells of different lengths into a square matrix in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054437/accumulating-cells-of-different-lengths-into-a-square-matrix-in-matlab). All you need to do is group your variables into a cell array first.

Comment: I have another problem, the number of variables are incremental e.g. in a loop, how I can group it?

Comment: Oops, looks like this is similar, but no full duplicate of the question I linked to. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the modified version of [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054437/accumulating-cells-of-different-lengths-into-a-square-matrix-in-matlab)'s answer to a previous, similar question

```
%# group the variables. If you would be generating them in a loop, you could use the loop
%# to group them, i.e. have something like
%# for i=1:n
%#    dtCell{i} = "function that generates dt_i"
%# end

dtCell = {dt1,dt2,dt3,dt};
nCells = length(dtCell);
maxVal = max(cellfun(@max,dtCell)); %# this way, I don't have to know vector orientation

%# you could replace the loop with calls to cellfun. 
%# While this may make you feel more Matlab-ish, it wouldn't be
%# faster, or more readable
out = zeros(maxVal,nCells);
for iCell = 1:nCells
   idx = dtCell{iCell}; %# this assignment is just for clarity 
   out(idx,iCell) = idx;
end
```

Comment: Nice, but you need to change the computation of the maximum value to something like `maxVal = max(vertcat(dtCell{:}));` to get the maximum value across *all* cells.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks for the heads-up! Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define example data:

```
dt1 = randi(10,10,1)-1;
dt2 = randi(10,7,1)-1;
dt3 = randi(10,6,1)-1;
dt4 = randi(10,5,1)-1; %// example data. Column vectors.
```

One approach is to create a mask with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and then fill values at the positions indicated by the mask:

```
dt = {dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4}; %// collect data into a cell array
n = cellfun(@numel, dt); %// length of each vector
mask = bsxfun(@le, (1:max(n)).', n); %// create mask
result = zeros(size(mask)); %// initiallize result with zeros
result(mask) = vertcat(dt{:}); %// fill in values.
```

Example result (with random data):

```
result =
     2     3     2     7
     3     9     8     6
     4     7     9     0
     4     3     5     7
     2     1     1     1
     1     7     7     0
     8     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     7     0     0     0
     8     0     0     0
```