# Matlab combine matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
student1      student2     student3
code  score   code  score  code  score 
1     20      1     100    1     22 
2     11      3     11     2     90
3     12      4     22     5     11
4     11
5     28
```

This question is related to [How do I combine uneven matrices into a single matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174631/matlab-how-to-combine-uneven-matric-into-single-matrix) but a little bit different. I want to combine n files which have different size. Each file read through loop. How I can get the output as shown below?

```
for i=1:n
  ....
  inputdata=[code score];
  sortdata= sortrows(inputdata,1);
end

Output
code s1  s2   s3 
1    20  100  22 
2    11  0    90
3    12  11   0
4    11  22   0
5    28  0    11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
inputdata=[code score];
sortdata = sortrows(inputdata,1);
```

use

```
completedata(code, n+1) = score;
```

This way you are using `code` as index to your final array. Initialising `completedata` before the loop would probably be a good idea.

```
completedata = [(1:codemax)', zeros(codemax, n)];
```

Comment: It contains the maximum number that `code` can contain, in your case `codemax=5`. You don't need it if you don't know it in advance, but then your `completedata` has to grow inside the for-loop which could be a performance bottleneck.