# How can I concatenate vectors to create non-rectangular matrices in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, jagged-arrays

Is there a way to create non-rectangular matrices? For example, if I have a matrix `a=[6 8 10]` and another matrix `b=[1 5]`, can I vertically concatenate them in order to obtain `[6 8 10]` in one row and `[1 5]` in another?

Comment: You can't.  MATLAB does not support ragged matrices.  One way you could get around this is to make a cell array, where each cell is a vector of unequal lengths.  Another way would be to create a matrix where those values that contain nothing get mapped to a preset number, like zero.  Therefore, you could concatenate `a` and `b` to be a matrix such that it becomes `[6 8 10; 1 5 0];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer is **no**.  MATLAB does not support [ragged or non-rectangular or non-square matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irregular_matrix).  One way you could get around this is to make a cell array, where each cell is a vector of unequal lengths.

Something like:

```
a = [6 8 10];
b = [1 5];
c = cell(1,2);
c{1} = a;
c{2} = b;

celldisp(c)

c{1} =

     6     8    10

c{2} =

     1     5
```

Another way would be to create a matrix where those values that contain nothing get mapped to a preset number, like zero.  Therefore, you could concatenate `a` and `b` to be a matrix such that it becomes `[6 8 10; 1 5 0];`.  If this is what you prefer, you can do something like this:

```
a = [6 8 10];
b = [1 5];
c = zeros(2, 3);
c(1,1:numel(a)) = a;
c(2,1:numel(b)) = b;
disp(c)

 6     8    10
 1     5     0
```

A more comprehensive treatise on this particular topic can be found in gnovice's answer: [How can I accumulate cells of different lengths into a matrix in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054437/how-can-i-accumulate-cells-of-different-lengths-into-a-matrix-in-matlab)

Another related answer was created by Jonas: [How do I combine uneven matrices into a single matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174631/how-do-i-combine-uneven-matrices-into-a-single-matrix)

Comment: hey rayreng..thanks for the response..it worked...thanks again!!