# How to change a cell array into vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, cell-array

I have a cell array which each cell is a point on (x,y) coordination (i.e, the cells are of size [1x2]). Is it possible to change it to matrix that those coordination points to be reserved?

Because when I used cell2mat, the peculiar coordination was change to the size of [1x1] while I need the coordinates.

my cell array is like this: `[0,2] [0,2] [1,3] [-13,10] [1,4] [-1,5]`

How I can change it to a vector that these coordinates can be used later for plotting?

Comment: Please provide your expected result format.

Comment: Maybe its better to ask that how I can plot a cell array while each cell is a peculiar coordinate on (x,y)?

Comment: @Biju Exactly as Luis has shown, and then `plot(result(:,1),result(:,2),'*')`

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I was just updating my answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>> myCell = {[1 2],[3 4],[5 6]}; %// example cell. Can have any size/shape
>> result = cell2mat(myCell(:)) %// linearize and then convert to matrix
result =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
```

To plot:

```
plot(result(:,1),result(:,2),'o') %// or change line spec
```

Comment: thanks Luis, but I want to plot these coordinates of [x y], while they are in cell format and don't need to get them seperated

Comment: In your question you say "change it to matrix"... Anyway, see updated answer

Comment: @LuisMendo what about `myCell = {[1 2 3],[3 4 ],[5 6 5 6 7]}` then how can i convert this cell array to vector?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to accomplish this:

```
c = {[1 2], [3 4], [5 6]};
v = vertcat(c{:});    % same as: cat(1,c{:})

plot(v(:,1), v(:,2), 'o')
```

Cell arrays in MATLAB can be expanded into a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), so the above call is equivalent to: `vertcat(c{1}, c{2}, c{3})`

Comment: what about `c= {[1 2 3],[3 4 ],[5 6 5 6 7]}` then how can i convert this cell array to vector?

Comment: in your case, you can only flatten the cell array into a one-dimensional vector (1x10 vector) as `v = [c{:}]` or `v = cat(2, c{:})`. You see when concatenating arrays, the dimensions must be **consistent**; you can't have a ["jagged"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irregular_matrix)

Comment: otherwise you can **pad** each cell with NaNs so that all rows have the same length before concatenation. You can find plenty of similar questions here on Stack Overflow, for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3054437/97160

Answer (score 0):

```
myCell = {[0,2] [0,2] [1,3] [-13,10] [1,4] [-1,5]};
hold on;
cellfun(@(c) plot(c(1),c(2),'o'),myCell);
```