# How to add vectors of different length in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do the following:
Let's say I have:

```
x1=[7];
x2=[3 4];
x3=[1 -1 5];
x4=[2 5 -1 3];
```

and I want to add them together.
I know it's not possible to add vectors of different dimensions, but what I'm trying to achieve is a new vector having:

```
v=[2 5+1 -1-1+3 3+5+4+7];
```

I tried to pad the relevant vectors with zeros, to get:

```
x1=[0 0 0 7];
x2=[0 0 3 4];
x3=[0 1 -1 5];
x4=[2 5 -1 3];
```

and then the addition will be natural, but couldn't find a way to do it.
Of course, I'm looking for an iterative method of doing that, meaning, every vector xi is the result of the i'th iteration, where the number of iterations, n, is known in advance.  (in the above example n=4)

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at this wrong, but there doesn't seem to be an easy to recognize pattern to your vector addition.

Comment: You're right, sorry... let me edit my post...

Comment: Does each vector have one more element that the previous one? And why don't you store vectors as cells of a cell array? That is, `x{1}`, `x{2}` etc. It would be easier and avoid `eval`

Comment: every vector is completely different from the one that was calculated in previous iteration.

Comment: Use this solution to get a regular matrix with the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054437/how-can-i-accumulate-cells-of-different-lengths-into-a-matrix-in-matlab . You want zeros on the left instead nans on the right, so you have to use `fcn = @(x) [zeros(1,maxSize-numel(x)) x];`. Finally, use `sum` to get the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought would be something like

```
x1 = [zeros(1, 4 - length(x1)) x1];
```

Where you would substitute max(all_your_arrays) for 4 in the above line.  If your arrays are in cell arrays you should be able to easily adapt that to a loop.