# How do I zip multiple cell arrays together?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

In many other languages, to zip a number of lists together means to take something like

```
((x1, x2, x3, x4), (y1, y2, y3, y3))
```

and turn it into

```
((x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4))
```

This of course generalises to lists

- with more than 2 sublists,
- whose sublists are not of length 4, and
- whose sublists may have entirely different lengths.

I find myself doing this a lot, so I thought I'd share the solution.

Comment: It's nice to see an interesting Matlab question in SO now and then :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: yep, this reminds me of an old question about doing `cell2mat` with padding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054437/how-can-i-accumulate-cells-of-different-lengths-into-a-matrix-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

```
function out = zipCells(varargin)
    % make sure all inputs are cell arrays
    assert(all(cellfun(@iscell, varargin)), 'Expecting cell arrays');

    % make them all of the same length
    mn = min(cellfun(@numel, varargin));
    in = cellfun(@(c) c(1:mn), varargin, 'UniformOutput',false);

    % zip lists
    out = cellfun(@(varargin) varargin, in{:}, 'UniformOutput',false);
end
```

*(The last line is using [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) to expand the cell array of cell arrays `in{:}`)*

Example:

```
>> c = zipCells({'x','y','z'}, {1,2}, {'a','b','c'})
c = 
    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}
>> c{:}
ans = 
    'x'    [1]    'a'
ans = 
    'y'    [2]    'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If **all cells have the same length**, there's a simple solution without `cellfun`, `arrayfun` or loops. It is based on the fact that [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) (inspite of its name) can be applied to a cell array:

   ```
   function out = zipCells(varargin)
   n = numel(varargin{1});
   out = mat2cell(reshape([varargin{:}], n, []), ones(1, n)).';
   ```
2. In the **general case**: trim cells to minimum length (two uses of `cellfun`) and proceed as above:

   ```
   function out = zipCells(varargin)
   n = min(cellfun(@numel, varargin));
   varargin = cellfun(@(c) c(1:n), varargin, 'uniformoutput', 0);
   out = mat2cell(reshape([varargin{:}], n, []), ones(1, n)).';
   ```
3. An extension to allow **input cells with different orientations** (row/column):

   ```
   function out = zipCells(varargin)
   n = min(cellfun(@numel, varargin));
   varargin = cellfun(@(c) reshape(c(1:n), 1,[]), varargin, 'uniformoutput', 0);
   out = mat2cell(reshape([varargin{:}], n, []), ones(1, n)).';
   ```

Comment: `num2cell(.,2)` can also be used to simplify the `mat2cell(.,ones(1,n))` call

Comment: @Amro Strange how these functions' names don't reflect all they can do. I guess their functionality was extended but the name was kept

Answer (score 0):

You can of course chan everything together, but the names should help describe what's happening:

```
function output = zipCells(varargin)

numComponents = min(cellfun(@length, varargin));
makeComponentI = @(i) cellfun(@(c) c{i}, varargin, 'UniformOutput', false);
output = arrayfun(makeComponentI, 1:numComponents, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Here's it in action:

```
>> pairs = zipCells({'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'}, {1 2 3 4})
pairs = 
    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}
>> pairs{:}
ans = 
    'a'    [1]
ans = 
    'b'    [2]
ans = 
    'c'    [3]
ans = 
    'd'    [4]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When the time limit has passed, consider accepting your answer to signal to the StackOverflow community that you no longer need any help.