# What is the equivalent of the Python zip function in MATLAB?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a Python code below that will zip through two arrays and print the output. What would the equivalent of this code be in MATLAB?

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    print(i, j)
```

Comment: "Pro tip" - you already got answers, but for future's sake, it is helpful if you added a example of the expected output of that Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do.

The most natural method in MATLAB is iterating over the index:

```matlab
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

for i = 1:numel(x)
   disp([x(i), y(i)]);
end
```

The alternative is to concatenate the two arrays. MATLAB's for loop iterates over the columns of the array:

```matlab
for i = [x;y]
   disp(i.');
end
```

Note that this alternative is typically much less efficient, because concatenation requires copying all the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can `iterate` through the index, matlab likes `for` loop.

```
matlab
for i=1:5
   x(i), y(i)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For MATLAB, there is no equivalent for the python `zip` function; if you were looking for something like that, I would recommend checking out [this SO answer about creating a zip function in MATLAB.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165932/how-do-i-zip-multiple-cell-arrays-together)

Otherwise, iterating through indices works.

```
% Create lists
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [1 2 3 4 5];

% Assuming lists are same length, iterate through indices
for i = 1:length(x)
    disp([x(i) y(i)]);
end
```