# Accumulate observations based on date stamp in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, reshape

If I have the following data-set

```
A =

20061201         100
20061201          10
20061201           9
20061202          15
20061202          50
20061204          40
20061204          16
20061204          12
```

`column 1` has dates while `columns 2` has corresponding observations
where `.` corresponds to no observation.

I expect the output to be something like

```
row 1: 20061201  100 10 9 
row 2: 20061202   15 50 .
row 3: 20061204   40 16 12
```

how can I do that, any tips?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use reshape?

Comment: it may require equal size vectors when for one date there will be lets say 10 observations and for others more or less.

Comment: How is it specified how many observations correspond to each date? Your question is unclear

Comment: @Jessi - That still doesn't explain why you can't use `reshape`.  I don't understand your problem statement.

Comment: Maybe I am using it wrong then, could you advise?

Comment: I have added an answer.. i have used cell arrays as it is appropriate for your problem.. if you need changes, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `unique` and `accumarray`

```
[uVals,~,subs] = unique(A(:,1));
out = [num2cell(uVals), accumarray(subs,A(:,2),[],@(x) {x.'})]
```

**Your Sample Input:**

```
>> A

A =

20061201         100
20061201          10
20061201           9
20061202          15
20061202          50
20061204          40
20061204          16
20061204          12
```

**Results:**

```
>> out

out =  

[20061201]    [1x3 double]
[20061202]    [1x2 double]
[20061204]    [1x3 double]
```

I have used `cell-Array` for the output.. you don't have to pad `.` to the deficient rows in this case. If you want to display a particular cell, you could use `{}` instead of `()` like this..

```
>> out{1,2}

ans =

100    10     9

>> out{2,2}

ans =

15    50
```

---

Here is a method (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3054577/2111163) answer) you might use if you insist to obtain a matrix instead of cell-array. I also suggest, you use `NaN`(Not-a-Number) padding instead of `.`

```
[uVals,~,subs] = unique(A(:,1));
valC = accumarray(subs,A(:,2),[],@(x) {x.'});
maxSize = max(cellfun(@numel,valC));
valMat = cellfun(@(x) [x nan(1,maxSize-numel(x))],valC,'uni',0);
valMat = vertcat(valMat{:});
out = [uVals, valMat];
```

**Results for the sample Input:**

```
>> out

out =

20061201         100          10           9
20061202          15          50         NaN
20061204          40          16          12
```